# Manifest merger failed while trying to add Google Admob in the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

This is the error shown in Build output after syncing.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0] C:\Users\This PC.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ee2b0372227ab442cb0dd06c2a32a8a5\jetified-play-services-ads-20.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of your min Sdk version, right now you have version 15, This creates an error because your google admob requires a min sdk version of 16.

You can change your minSdkVersion in your build.gradle(Module: app) file then rebuild your prodject and this error should disappear.